# property 'throwerror' does not exist on type 'typeof observable angular 8

Tags: angular, rxjs, angular8

I am getting a

> property 'throwerror' does not exist on type 'typeof observable

error when running my code.

my code:

```
import { Observable, BehaviorSubject, throwError } from 'rxjs';

export class TokenInterceptorService implements HttpInterceptor {
   .....
  intercept(
    request: HttpRequest<any>,
    next: HttpHandler
  ): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(this.addToken(request, this.auth.getToken())).pipe(
      catchError(error => {
        if (error instanceof HttpErrorResponse) {
          switch (( error as HttpErrorResponse).status) {
            case 401:
              return this.handle401Error(error);
            case 403:
              return this.handle403Error(request, next);
          }
        } else {
          return Observable.throwError()
        }
      })
    )  }
}
```

I am using angular cli: 8.

Comment: that's an independent operator as of today, just use `return throwError();`

Answer (score 0):

The documentation says

ThrowError can be used composing with other Observable, such as in a mergeMap, switchMap etc. throwError is introduced in RxJS 6 and we need to use it in place of `Observable.throw().`

So if you use `RxJS 6` you can just use `throwError('Error Occurred');`